# Is there a way to create a for loop with char variables to create several plots?

Tags: for-loop, ggplot2, filter, char

I am novel with R and I cannot find a solution to my problem. I guess the problem is pretty simple. I have a df with 4 variables: date, SKU_code, SKU_category and sales_amount. I want to create a for loop to plot n figures, with n equal to the number of SKU_category. In other words this is the code I want to transform in a for loop. It works, but I have more than 50 categories so it is not efficient:

```
dfsales_red_cat <- dfsales %>% group_by(date, SKU_code, SKU_category) %>% summarize(y=sum(sales_amount))
dfsales_red_C01 <- dfsales_red_cat %>% filter(SKU_category =="C01")
dfsales_red_C01 <- dfsales_red_C01[,c(1,2,4)]
ggplot(dfsales_red_C01,aes(x=date,y=y,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+labs(title="C01", y='Sales',x='Year')

dfsales_red_C02 <- dfsales_red_cat %>% filter(SKU_category =="C02")
dfsales_red_C02 <- dfsales_red_C02[,c(1,2,4)]
ggplot(dfsales_red_C02,aes(x=date,y=y,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+labs(title="C02", y='Sales',x='Year')

...and so on...
```

I tried with this, but it didn't work

```
dfsales_red_cat <- dfsales %>% group_by(date, SKU_code, SKU_category) %>% summarize(y=sum(sales_amount))

cat <- unique(dfsales_red_cat$SKU_category)

for (i in cat) {
    dfsales_red_i <- dfsales_red_cat %>% filter(SKU_category==i)
  dfsales_red_i <- dfsales_red_i[,c(1,2,4)]
  ggplot(dfsales_red_i,aes(x=date,y=y,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+
    labs(title=i, y='Sales',x='Year')
}
```

Thank you for your help.

This is part of the original table dfsales_red_cat (>10000 rows) and formats are date, char, char, number:

```
    DATE SKU_code SKU_category sales_amount
1   2016-01-03  Z0003   C13 298380.0
2   2016-01-03  Z0005   C10 225433.6
3   2016-01-03  Z0006   C10 2246883.8
4   2016-01-03  Z0007   C10 653144.4
5   2016-01-03  Z0009   C15 170233.4
```

Comment: Hi Davide, can you elaborate on what did not work? I noticed inside the ggplot function for the loop, you have ggplot(dfsales_red_i,aes(x=week,...), shouldn't it be date?

Comment: Your comment is right. I changed ggplot(dfsales_red_i,aes(x=week,...) into ggplot(dfsales_red_i,aes(x=date,...), but it didn't plot anything. On the contrary, if I run every code as in the first box everything works fine

Comment: It still doesn't work? Whats the error? And if dfsales_red_cat is not too huge,  can you dput(dfsales_red_cat) and paste the output

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestion. Changed the original question. I don't have any error message. It doesn't plot anything.

Comment: Sorry is this all your data? How are you going to plot line when there is only one data point in each subset?

Comment: No these are the first 5 lines. Unfortunately there are >10000 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either `print` , store it in a list and `print` or simply facet_wrap. First to get something like your data:

```
sample_dates=seq(as.Date("2016-01-03"),as.Date("2016-12-03"),length.out=50)

df = expand.grid(
date = sample_dates,
SKU_code = c("Z0003","Z0005","Z0006"),
SKU_category = c("C13","C10")
)

df$date = as.Date(df$date)
df$sales_amount = runif(nrow(df))
cat <- unique(df$SKU_category)
```

Just `print`:

```
for (i in cat) {
  df_i <- subset(df,SKU_category==i)
  g = ggplot(df_i,aes(x=date,y=sales_amount,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + 
  theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+
  labs(title=i, y='Sales',x='Year')
  print(g)
}
```

Store in list:

```
plts = lapply(cat,function(i){
g = ggplot(df_i,aes(x=date,y=sales_amount,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + 
      theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+
      labs(title=i, y='Sales',x='Year')
return(g)
})
plts[[1]]
```

Or:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=date,y=sales_amount,colour=SKU_code,group=SKU_code)) + 
theme(legend.position="none") + geom_line()+
labs(y='Sales',x='Year')+
facet_wrap(~SKU_category)
```